# Java Jackson serializer including FQCN

Tags: java, json, class, jackson

I'm trying to create a generic Jackon polymorphic serializer that is able to serialize and deserialize to and from JSON with this format including the fqcn of the class of the object:

```
{
  "fqcn": "full qualified class name of the object",
  "data": "serialized object"
}
```

This wrapper should be applied to any object, so for example this will be the JSON representation of a HashMap> object:

```
{
  "fqcn": "java.util.HashMap",
  "data": {
    "key1": {
      "fqcn": "java.util.ArrayList",
      "data": [
        {
          "fqcn": "java.lang.String",
          "data": "value1"
        },
        {
          "fqcn": "java.lang.String",
          "data": "value2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "key2": { 
      ... 
    }
  }
}
```

I could use a MixIn annotation all objects with `@JsonTypeInfo`

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
public interface ObjMixin {

}

---

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, ObjMixin.class);
```

However, the format does not match with the required format: `{"fqcn": ..., "data": ...}`

I've also tried to register a StdConverter to convert any objects to a wrapper like this:

```
public class ObjectWrapper {

    private String fqcn;
    private Object data;

    public ObjectWrapper(Object obj) {
        this.fqcn = obj.getClass.getCanonicalName();
        this.data = obj;
    }

}
```

However it is not possible to create a `StdDelegatingSerializer` for `Object.class`.

With a custom `StdSerializer` like the following I am getting `StackOverflowError`:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Object obj, JsonGenerator jsonGen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    jsonGen.writeStartObject();
    jsonGen.writeStringField("fqcn", obj.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    jsonGen.writeFieldName("data");
    if (obj instanceof Iterable) {
        jsonGen.writeStartArray();
        // Recursive serialization of all elements in the iterable
        jsonGen.writeEndArray();
    } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
        jsonGen.writeStartObject();
        // Recursive serialization of all elements in the map
        jsonGen.writeEndObject();
    } else {
        // Infinite recursion here because I'm defining this serializer for Object.class
        serializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(obj, jsonGen); 
    }
}
```

Does anyone know any other solution to be able to achieve this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom serializer and custom serializer provider to wrap every object you want to serialize into this wrapper object (EDIT: that did not work recusrively, updated the code to not use the wrapper object but write the fields instead):

```
public class FQCNTest {

    @Test
    public void doTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper om = getObjectMapper();

        final Object obj = getTestObject();

        final String json = om.writeValueAsString(obj);

        System.out.println(json); // {"fqcn":"java.util.HashMap","data":{"k":{"fqcn":"java.lang.String","data":"v"}}}

        final Object obj2 = getTestValue();

        final String json2 = om.writeValueAsString(obj2);

        System.out.println(json2); // {"fcqn":"java.lang.String","data":"hello"}

        final Object obj3 = null;

        final String json3 = om.writeValueAsString(obj3);

        System.out.println(json3); // null
    }

    private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final SerializerProvider sp = mapper.getSerializerProviderInstance();
        mapper.setSerializerProvider(new CustomSerializerProvider(sp, mapper.getSerializerFactory()));
        return mapper;
    }

    private Object getTestObject() {
        final HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("k", "v");
        return hashMap;
    }

    private Object getTestValue() {
        return "hello";
    }

}

class CustomSerializerProvider extends DefaultSerializerProvider {

    private final SerializerProvider defaultInstance;

    protected CustomSerializerProvider(final SerializerProvider defaultInstance, final SerializerFactory f) {
        super(defaultInstance, defaultInstance.getConfig(), f);
        this.defaultInstance = defaultInstance;

    }

    @Override
    public WritableObjectId findObjectId(final Object forPojo, final ObjectIdGenerator<?> generatorType) {
        return defaultInstance.findObjectId(forPojo, generatorType);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Object> serializerInstance(final Annotated annotated, final Object serDef) throws JsonMappingException {
        return new CustomSerializer();
    }

    @Override
    public Object includeFilterInstance(final BeanPropertyDefinition forProperty, final Class<?> filterClass) {
        try {
            return defaultInstance.includeFilterInstance(forProperty, filterClass);
        } catch (final JsonMappingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean includeFilterSuppressNulls(final Object filter) throws JsonMappingException {
        return defaultInstance.includeFilterSuppressNulls(filter);
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultSerializerProvider createInstance(final SerializationConfig config, final SerializerFactory jsf) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeValue(final JsonGenerator gen, final Object value) throws IOException {
        new CustomSerializer().serialize(value, gen, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeValue(final JsonGenerator gen, final Object value, final JavaType rootType) throws IOException {
        super.serializeValue(gen, value, rootType);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeValue(final JsonGenerator gen, final Object value, final JavaType rootType, final JsonSerializer<Object> ser) throws IOException {
        super.serializeValue(gen, value, rootType, ser);

    }

}

class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    protected CustomSerializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final Object value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            provider.defaultSerializeValue(value, gen);
            return;
        }

        final Class<?> clazz = value.getClass();
        final JsonSerializer<Object> serForClazz = provider.findValueSerializer(clazz);

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("fqcn", clazz.getCanonicalName());
        gen.writeFieldName("data");

        if (value instanceof Iterable) {
            gen.writeStartArray();
            for (final Object e : ((Iterable<?>) value)) {
                final JsonSerializer<Object> ser = new CustomSerializer();
                ser.serialize(e, gen, provider);
            }
            gen.writeEndArray();
        } else if (value instanceof Map) {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            // Recursive serialization of all elements in the map
            for (final Map.Entry<?, ?> e : ((Map<?, ?>) value).entrySet()) {
                final String key = e.getKey().toString(); // need to handle keys better
                final Object mapValue = e.getValue();
                gen.writeFieldName(key);
                final JsonSerializer<Object> ser = new CustomSerializer();
                ser.serialize(mapValue, gen, provider);
            }
            gen.writeEndObject();
        } else {
            serForClazz.serialize(value, gen, provider);
        }

        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

Note: this code may contain too much stuff that is not necessary, I just took it far enough to make it work for the specific example. (and did not test deserialization, that may be a totally different thing)